# imagemagick convert does not work through php exec() but works through command line

Tags: php, pdf, imagemagick

When I try to convert pdf to php via command line:

```
convert 1.pdf 2.jpg
```

it works and gives me jpg image. But then I try to convert via php `exec()` it doesn't work.

```
exec("convert 1.pdf 2.jpg");
```

Process starts but I haven't result. I try to use

```
putenv("PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin")
```

and full path to file but it doesn't help.

I have a new detail of my problem: when I run my php script via command line - it works. But when I try to run it in my browser process starts and works a few seconds (~15 sec) but I haven't result.

Comment: Add `2>&1` to the end of the command, and use [the second argument of `exec`](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php) to see the full output. Personal preference - use absolute paths everywhere, relative ones are a headache.

Comment: Thank you for answer. I have a new detail of my problem: when I run my php script via command line - it works. But when I try to run it in my browser process starts but I haven't result. 
P.S. I tried to use the second argument of exec () - each time I had an empty array.

Answer (score 0):

I also had a development where I needed to convert pdf to image. I also used imagemagick. In my case, my web hoster has disabled the PHP function exec() for security reason. Is it possible that you have the same problem?

So, I was not able to use PHP to run imagemagick. My web hoster asks me to use a Pearl script and then it was working.

I hope my remark can help you.

Comment: I can use exec() in my scripts. Maybe I will try to use Perl like you. Thank you for answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the PECL library for ImageMagick. Gives you a lot of options using PHP to work with imagemagick

http://php.net/manual/en/book.imagick.php